# Getting CPU time limit exceeded error

Tags: apex

trigger

```
trigger UpdateRelIntConIds5 on Contract_Group_Association__c (after delete, after insert, after update) {
    Set<Id> accounts = new Set<Id>();

    Set<Id> cons = new Set<Id>();

    if (Trigger.old != null) {
        system.debug('inside update');
        for (Contract_Group_Association__c c : Trigger.old) {
            if (c.Internal_Contract_Group__c != null)
                cons.add(c.Internal_Contract_Group__c);
        }
    }


    if (Trigger.new != null) {
        system.debug('inside insert');
        for (Contract_Group_Association__c c : Trigger.new) {
            if (c.Internal_Contract_Group__c != null)
                cons.add(c.Internal_Contract_Group__c);
        }
    }

    List<Customer_Groups_Association__c> conGroup = [select Internal_Contact_Group__c from Customer_Groups_Association__c where Internal_Contract_Group__c in :cons];
system.debug('conGroup'+conGroup.size());
    for (Customer_Groups_Association__c cx : conGroup) {
        accounts.add(cx.Internal_Contact_Group__c);
          system.debug('cx.Internal_Contact_Group__c: '+cx.Internal_Contact_Group__c);
    }   
   system.debug('Groups'+accounts);
    UpdateRelatedInternalContractIds ur = new UpdateRelatedInternalContractIds(accounts);
    ur.go();
}
```

Related class:

```
global class UpdateRelatedInternalContractIds {
    public Set<Id> accounts {get; set;}

    public UpdateRelatedInternalContractIds(Set<Id> accounts) {
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }

    public void go() {
        Set<Id> contractGroups = new Set<Id>();

        Map<String, Set<String>> customers = new Map<String, Set<String>>();

        if (accounts == null)
            return;

        List<Customer_Groups_Association__c> clist = [select id, Internal_Contract_Group__c, Internal_Contact_Group__c from Customer_Groups_Association__c where Internal_Contact_Group__c in :accounts];

        if (clist != null) {
            for (Customer_Groups_Association__c c : clist) {
                contractGroups.add(c.Internal_Contract_Group__c);

                Set<String> t = customers.get(c.Internal_Contact_Group__c);

                if (t == null) {
                    t = new Set<String>();
                    customers.put(c.Internal_Contact_Group__c, t);
                }

                t.add(c.Internal_Contract_Group__c);
            }
        }

        Map<String, Set<String>> contractIds = new Map<String, Set<String>>();

        List<Contract_Group_Association__c> dlist = [select id, Internal_Contract__r.Internal_Contract_ID__c, Internal_Contract_Group__c from Contract_Group_Association__c where Internal_Contract_Group__c in :contractGroups];

        if (dlist != null) {
            for (Contract_Group_Association__c d : dlist) {
                Set<String> t = contractIds.get(d.Internal_Contract_Group__c);

                if (t == null) {
                    t = new Set<String>();
                    contractIds.put(d.Internal_Contract_Group__c, t);
                }

                t.add(d.Internal_Contract__r.Internal_Contract_ID__c);
            }
        }

        List<Account> customerList = [select id, Related_Internal_Contract_IDs__c from Account where id in :accounts];

        for (Account c : customerList) {
            String result = '';

            if (customers.containsKey(c.id)) {
                system.debug('customer@@' + c);
                for (String s : customers.get(c.id)) {
                    if (!contractIds.containsKey(s))
                        continue;

                    for (String x : contractIds.get(s)) {
                        if (result != '')
                            result += ',';

                        result += x;    
                    }
                }
            }

            c.Related_Internal_Contract_IDs__c = result;
        }

        update customerList;
    }
}
```

Comment: String concatenation eats a lot (probably).  `result+= String.join(new List<String>(contractIds.get(s)),', ');` can save some time

Answer (score 1):

Not checked your full code but if you are checking for isUpdate and isInsert please use 
`Trigger.isUpdate` or `Trigger.isInsert` for update and insert operation consecutively. (I am guessing based on your system debug)

here `Trigger.old` will check for all the existing records **BEFORE UPDATE** and `Trigger.New` checks for **AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT**.
So basically your existing data are coming twice the time in your trigger before update and after update.

Change that and try again if the error still exist meanwhile I will look your code.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, remove following `if` conditions from your `trigger`

`if (Trigger.old != null) {`
and
`if (Trigger.new != null) {`

because they are unnecessary, as you are looping through both of the collections, besides, **trigger** won't fire if there is no record. So, logically that was a waste.

Now, put a check before you **SOQL** here like

```
if (cons.size> 0) List<Customer_Groups_Association__c> conGroup = [select Internal_Contact_Group__c from Customer_Groups_Association__c where Internal_Contract_Group__c in :cons];
```

**Problem in your handler class**

`List<Customer_Groups_Association__c> clist = [select id, Internal_Contract_Group__c, Internal_Contact_Group__c from Customer_Groups_Association__c where Internal_Contact_Group__c in :accounts];`

You are querying again `Customer_Groups_Association__c` (on line 16)with the same filters as used in your trigger (also mentioned above). This is another waste, and with the increase in data you might even hit `too many SOQL (101)` error in single execution context.

Make it a part of your constructor, as you did with `accounts`.

Then, remove the `if` check, which is unnecessary for the same reason as explained above

`if (clist != null) { // remove this as well`

and

`if (dlist != null) {`

Also, as mentioned in another answer, wrap your code to logical blocks (what you wanna do when the record is updated/deleted/inserted) using [trigger context variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71134/discussion-on-answer-by-mahmood-getting-cpu-time-limit-exceeded-error).